# Rasa scheduler reminder how to return a message to the client, such as an app

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I want to use rasa to make a schedule reminder now.I sent a request to rasa.
URL is http://localhost:5006/webhooks/rest/webhook
request body is:

```
{
  "sender": "rasa",
  "message": "Remind me to go to the meeting after one minutes"
}
```

But the schedule is up, I want to send a notification to the client, such as the app, to remind the user what to do.

How can I do it? Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reminders and external events](https://legacy-docs-v1.rasa.com/core/reminders-and-external-events/) to send notifications to the user.